# Custom function - add as column to frame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a function which creates a dataframe, and a sub-function which does some diff's on that data frame to come up with a result - how do I add this result as a column to my dataframe.

```
 def custom_compare_eq(series, other):
        length = len(series.values)
        for i in range(length):
            r1 = eval(str(series.values[i]))
            r2 = eval(str(other.values[i]))

            if type(r1) != type(r2):
                yield False
            else:
                if type(r1) == int:
                    yield r1 == r2
                elif type(r1) == list:
                    yield set(r1) == set(r2)
    print('store the result output')
    result = list(custom_compare_eq(df.a_series, df.b_series))
    print('add new match column to df')
    df['match'] = result
    print(df)
```

the last print(df) I expected to have the new 'match' column but it does not :(

Comment: Please post a [mcve]

Comment: I think you need to do a `return` in your function instead of yield

Comment: @KevinChoonLiangYew all the yield's to returns or just one return at the end ?

Comment: You can try changing it to return as `yield` will give you a generator, not a value. But of course, you may need to update your code in your function.

Comment: Update it how else besides the yield ?

Comment: Your code works on me. Python indent is wrong in your question. Did you run your code with the right indent?